# Настройка проекта в Visual Studio. Пространства имен

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте. Не могу получить доступ к классам, которые должны быть в System.Windows. Intellisense показывает только два пункта. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: ссылки на библиотечные сборки в папке `references` указали?

Comment: @rdorn Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellisense показывает только пространства имен, которые доступны в подключенных к проекту сборках.

Кроме указания пространства имен в файле с исходным кодом, необходимо в настройках проекта указать ссылки на используемые библиотечные сборки. Для этого используется "папка" `references` в обозревателе проектов.